# Run .exe on remote machine with PSEXEC

Tags: pyinstaller, executable, remote-access, psexec

I am trying to run an .exe that sits on a remote machine with [PSEXEC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec), but it does not run properly.

The exe is a converted python script:

```
usage: WindowsUpdates3.exe [-h] [-v] [-m] [-i] [-u] [-r] [-s SKIP]

List, download and update Windows clients

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -v, --version         Show program version and exit
  -m, --list-missing    List missing updates
  -i, --list-installed  List installed updates
  -u, --update          List and install missing updates
  -r, --reboot          Reboot after installing updates if needed
  -s SKIP, --skip SKIP  Skips these KB numbers
```

I am able to run the .exe as intended with a PSEXEC console session:

```
PSEXEC \\<hostname> cmd
```

Navigate to the exe `my.exe -i`, run it and it works the same way if I execute it on the machine locally.

When I try to execute the file directly some fucntionality does not work

```
PSEXEC.exe \\<hostname> -h "C:\WindowsUpdates\WindowsUpdates3.exe" -i
...
C:\WindowsUpdates\WindowsUpdates3.exe exited on <hostname> with error code 0.
```

I am able to get the help-menu (`-h`) and the version (`-v`) of the exe with the above command.

The other arguments don't return anything but `code 0` and the `--update` argument throws a `com_error`: -2147024891, which translates to **access denied...**

How can this be as I have the same privileges as if I spawn a cmd terminal?